# Second CSS class not applying to div

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to break my html into separate php files and have an error I can't seem to crack. Here is the first file, index.php

```css
.topheader {
  background-color: #404040;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #404040;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
</head>

<div class="topheader">
  <h1>KivaGIS</h1>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h1>Footer</h1>
</div>
```

As of right now, only .topheader is applying to the html. I understand that both classes are identical, I plan to expand on each once I confirm they are applying individually. Can someone please take a look and advise why .footer wouldn't be applying to the sheet?

Here is a sample of the output on my machine

[image]

Comment: Please provide some working fiddle or link as seeing the code all looks good.

Comment: Seems working for me, try changing the `.footer`'s css to other values

Comment: @SahilDhir I added a sample image of my browser... what do you think I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you also show me the screenshot of the console (f12). targeting the footer div?

Comment: @SahilDhir So... apparently an old version of my css file is being loaded, despite it not existing anymore in the referenced folder. I used the developer tools per your suggestion and found the source files. It's loading the wrong file.

Comment: So just clear your cache . Link the correct css and everything will work ;)

Comment: Hahaha yes It happens sometimes :P

Answer (score 0):

Seems working for me, `.topheader` and `.footer` having different styles

```css
.topheader {
  background-color: #404040;
  color: blue;
  padding: 16px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #404040;
  color: red;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
</head>

<div class="topheader">
  <h1>I AM BLUE</h1>
</div>
<br>
<div class="footer">
  <h1>I AM RED</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Applying to your file, both `.topheader` and `.footer` class contain same style. just change the style values, you can see the difference

```
.topheader {
  background-color: #404040;
  color: white;
  padding:16px;
 }
.footer {
  background-color: #FFEE00;
  color: Red;
  padding:16px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code once and in your code check once href of your stylesheet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
.topheader {background-color: #404040;color: white;padding:16px;}
.footer {background-color: #404040;color: white;padding:16px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topheader">
  <h1>KivaGIS</h1>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h1>Footer</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this cleared it up a bit. This code works fine on my machine. I adjusted my files and moved everything in to the same directory. I think my code is being thrown off by the relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

As many on here pointed out, the code itself was fine. I did not realize that Chrome would cache the CSS file. I've spent all night updating the file without seeing any changes because Chrome was using an older version.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

As you can see from the attached screencap, I disabled the cache and everything is working perfectly now.